# infinite rerender material ui accordian

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm getting an infinite rerender when I try to make a controlled accordian component using the material ui accordian.
Here is my code, anybody have any ideas why it might be causing an infinite rerender?

```
  const [expanded, setExpanded] = React.useState([true, false, false]);

  const handleChange = idx => {
    const newState = expanded.map((value, i) => (i === idx ? !value : value));
    setExpanded(newState);
  };
```

And then the expanded and onChange props on the Accordian component are written as so:

```
<Accordion expanded={expanded[0]} onChange={handleChange(0)}>
```

Answer (score 1):

it is because on every render you are calling `handleChange(0)` which calls setExpanded which causes a rerender.
What you need to do is to pass handle change as a callback like this:

```js
<Accordion expanded={expanded[0]} onChange={()=>handleChange(0)}>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an array to do it.

Add a unique id to each Accordion like this

```
<Accordion expanded={expanded === "first"} onChange={setExpanded("first")} />
```